# remove the arrow from last cell to first cell in latex flow chart

Tags: latex, flowchart

I would like to remove the arrow from the last cell to the first. Can someone please say how to do so?

Here is the latex code:

```
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Edit,
  \LaTeX, Bib\TeX/ biber, make\-index, \LaTeX}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the smart diagram package, there is an option to disable the back arrow from the last cell to the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true}

\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Edit,
  \LaTeX, Bib\TeX/ biber, make\-index, \LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

[image]